# I have an 'n' number of array and how can I concat all array into a single array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I concat 'n' number of arrays into a single array using jQuery.

```
     a1 = [a,b,c,d,f];
     a2 = [h,g,f,r];
     ...............
     an = [r,e,c,g,s,g];
```

and I need to get like

```
     A = [a,b,c,d,f,h,g,f,r,.....,r,e,c,g,s,g];
```

Please help. Thank you in advance for all replay

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of arrays, or are you actually using `n` distinct variables?

Comment: See this its really help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `array concat` method

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oxusap/1/edit)

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b"];
var arr2 = ["c", "d"];

var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);

console.log(arr3);  // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

You can find more info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 1):

```
var A=a1.concat(a2,a3,a4,....,an);
```

Comment: I don't know the number of arrays it is a variable

Comment: The way mentioned is the right way. Now the question is how are you getting the arrays?

Comment: I've got the answer right here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13582972/1835379 you can check if a variable exists, and loop though them, provided they have consistent naming.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your arrays are all named `a<x>`, and global variables, you can loop through them on the window object as follows:

```
var output = [];
for(var i = 1; window['a'+i]; i++){
    output = output.concat(window['a'+i]);
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/r2DcT/)

Output will then, at the end of the loop, be a concatenation of all the arrays.

`window['a'+i]` will refer to the `a1 - aX` arrays, since global variables are properties of the `window` object. As such, these are all identical:

```
var output = "Some content"

console.log(output);
console.log(window.output);
console.log(window['output']);
// These will all return "Some content"
```

You can also manually concatenate them like this if you know how many you have:

```
output = a1.concat(a2,a3,a<x>...);
```

Comment: Tested and working in Chrome. You can't have gaps in the array numbering, however. (Having arrays like: `a1, a2, a3, a5` will not let this concatenate `a5`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.concat([1,2,3],[4,5])
```

or

```
[1,2,3].concat([4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with $.merge; example:

```
var new = $.merge( [0,1,2], [2,3,4] ); // new = [0,1,2,2,3,4]
```

Comment: jQuery.merge merges the contents of two arrays together into the first array. The concat() method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array.

Comment: Don't use jQuery for something that js has native functionality for.
Also, don't use `new` as variable name, it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Sure sure, i write "new" by mistake. I never use "concat", i will try in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat()` method.

```
var a1 = ["a","b","c","d","f"]; 
var a2 = ["h","g","f","r"]

var a3 = a1.concat(a2);

console.log(a3);  // Outputs: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "h", "g", "f", "r"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standart function `concat`.

Answer (score -1):

Something similar to:

```
for(a2...an){
    a1 = $.merge(a1,next);
}
```